# Working with derived balances in models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to keep track of an invoices balance once a customer has made a payment, how can i achieve that?

I have nested resources

```
resources :invoices do
  resources :payments
end
```

The invoices model is as follows:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :customer, :inverse_of => :invoices
 attr_accessible :due_date, :invoice_date, :reading_ids, :customer_id, :customer, :status, :amount,     :balance

 has_many :invoice_items, :dependent => :destroy
 has_many :payments, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

The payments model is as follows:

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :amount, :method, :payment_date, :reference_no, :invoice_id
  belongs_to :invoice
end
```

Whenever a customer makes a payment, I would like to subtract the payment from the balance and store a new balance for that invoice. This then becomes the new balance for the invoice.

How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve what you want will be to use [ActiveRecord::Callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html):

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :amount, :method, :payment_date, :reference_no, :invoice_id
  belongs_to :invoice
  after_create :update_invoice_balance

  def update_invoice_balance
    current_balance = self.invoice.balance
    self.invoice.update_attributes(balance: current_balance - self.amount)
  end
end
```

Another way that you may try will be to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in your `Invoice` model:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :customer, :inverse_of => :invoices
  attr_accessible :payments_attributes, :due_date, :invoice_date, :reading_ids, :customer_id, :customer, :status, :amount, :balance

  has_many :invoice_items, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :payments, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :payments
end
```

In this case, you will be creating payments from `invoces#edit` page and you can construct your form this way: you will have "Pay Now" button that will inject `payments/_new_form` into `invoices/_edit_form`, then any time the user will enter a value into `amount` field of `payments/_new_form`, you will update the value of balance field of `invoices/_edit_form` with the value from `amount` field of `payments/_new_form` using JavaScript. Submitting `invoices/_edit_form` will save both objects. If you take this approach, check out [nested_form gem](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form), it makes things easier. However, I still reccommend the callback approach, since it guarantees that invoice balance is updated *every time* (even if you do it from the console, not UI).